# best way to create a dict like {0:0,1:1,2:2} using python

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code :

```
print dict(range(3),range(3))
```

but it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 7, in <module>
    print dict(range(3),range(3))
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension which works in Python 2.7 or newer:

```
{ i: i for i in range(3) }
```

Or for older versions of Python you can do this:

```
dict((i, i) for i in range(3))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
 dict(zip(range(3),range(3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A longer but easy to understand way:

```
d={}
for x in range(3):
    d[x]=x

print d
```